# How to verify what modules are active on my server?

Tags: htaccess, server

While trying to solve a problem on my website, a recommendation about my .htaccess file I got was

> First of all, please check on the
>   server for all the different modules
>   if they are enabled, and once they
>   are, remove the

```
<IfModule
 ...></IfModule>
```

> blocks. They are
>   putting an unnecessary strain on your
>   server.

I don't know where should I look to see if modules are active - is it in the CMS? in the httpd.conf file? in the files on my server? should I make a slight modification in the .htaccess as a test?
But more than that, could the recommendation self be not appropriate?
Thanks.

Here is the .htaccess file for which the recommendation has been made:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>

  <filesMatch "\\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>

  <filesMatch "\\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
  </filesMatch>

  <filesMatch "\\.(xml|txt)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, public, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>

  <filesMatch "\\.(html|htm|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset ETag
</ifModule>

FileETag None

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset Last-Modified
</ifModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?foo\.com$
RewriteRule .? http://foo.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: I think you need more information from the person who said that. What modules? Apache modules? What do they mean by "blocks"?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I've added the .htaccess file based on which the person made the recommendation. I don't really understand what they mean and couldn't get more details about that from them, that's why I ask here, thought that people with more knowledge than me could understand that easier. Just a second, I only now see that the question has been edited before being posted - I should have used code tags in the quote tag. Will edit right away!

Comment: I've corrected the question, now the recommendation contains all the original information.

Comment: The way to find what's active depends on your server. Some will be in the http.conf file, but others may be loaded dynamically. Do you have some sort of control panel, or do you have access to the server itself?

Comment: It is a Wordpress website - so I guess it is an Apache server. I have FTP access to the website's files, access details to the LunarPages CMS and access to the Wordpress interface.

Comment: Where did you get the advice about the ifModule thing? This is true wherever the module failing would result in the site itself failing (such as mod_rewrite), so it's not entirely necessary to check for the module first. However, if mod_headers failed, your site would still work - unless you did not check with ifModule first, because then htaccess file would be invalid.

Answer (score 5):

If PHP is run as apache module, you can use the `phpinfo()` function. Search for the Apache section (usually `apache2handler`) and look for the row with "Loaded Modules":

[image: apache2handler section of phpinfo()]

Comment: Not listed on my shared hosting, unfortunately.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt It is possible that your shared hosting is not using Apache + mod_php, but instead nginx/Apache/... with php-fpm or even php-cgi. Look for the *Server API* line on top of the page (mine says FPM/FastCGI for php-fpm).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean apache modules you can run the below to list which modules you have loaded:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

Comment: `-bash: apachectl: command not found` sob :(

Comment: You could try: `find / apachectl | grep apachectl`

Comment: `ModSecurity: Failed to open debug log file: /var/log/apache2/modsec_debug.log` then `cat: /var/log/apache2/modsec_debug.log: Permission denied` sob :(

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have those modules loaded then it doesn't look anything's going to break on your site, it's just not going to have the best cache control settings. So leave out the ifmodules as you can't even load them if they aren't loaded. The apache website says

> In normal operation, directives need not be placed in  sections.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#ifmodule

Answer (score 1):

> First of all, please check on the server for all the different modules
>   if they are enabled, and once they are, remove the <IfModule 
>   ...></IfModule>

About your query:
you need to check whether those modules are enabled on server, and if they are you can remove the if condition from htaccess:

e.g. if module **mod_expires.c** is enabled then you can remove the `<IfModule  mod_expires.c></IfModule>` and you'll keep only this part:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
```

so you're not checking anymore to see if that module is enabled because you already did that.

Answer (score 0):

1) just add to `.htaccess`

```
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
deny from YOUR.IP 


</ifModule>
```

2) refresh your website
3) if you are out of game now, `mod_expires` is active
4) delete `deny from YOUR.IP` from  `ifModule mod_expires.c`