# Enable gzip compression On Worpress Hosted on Godaddy

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, godaddy

I have a site hosted on Godaddy, I need to enable gzip compression on my website as it recommended on speed test, and I have added below content to .htaccess

```
# BEGIN GZIP
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
# END GZIP
```

My final htaccess look like

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN GZIP
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
# END GZIP
```

But when I load my website and open the .htaccess file again the file content becomes as reset to initial, like,

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My godaddy hosting plan is Deluxe Classic Hosting Linux.

**Edit:**

I got it working by stopping all system process on godaddy, then edit again the .htaccess file resolved the issue.

But this was for short time, after few minutes the .htaccss file revert to it's original content.

Can any one give what can be the issue?

Comment: I don't know, but it kind of sounds like a (WordPress?) "security" plugin of some kind is perhaps reverting the file back to a previous version (ie. blocking changes)?! What file permissions are set for the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GoDaddy by default enables mod_deflate and globally sets the compression types on all packages purchased in the last few years. Only classic accounts require manual intervention.

> **[SOURCE](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6946/enabling-mod_deflate-with-your-hosting-account?countrysite=uk)**
>
> Our Linux Web Hosting hosting accounts have mod_deflate enabled by
>   default. This compresses all text type files requested from it. You
>   can disable mod_deflate on a per-directory basis and it applies
>   recursively. You can place the following in a .htaccess file to
>   disable mod_deflate:
>
> `SetEnvIf Request_URI .* no-gzip=1`
>
> **Classic**
>
> Our Classic Hosting accounts do not enable mod_deflate at the global
>   level, but you can enable it in your .htaccess file.

It's always best practice to contact your host first, if they are no help then your with the wrong provider, also just so you know, not all hosts require `<IfModule>`, so if you are on a classic account remove the `<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>` as GoDaddy does not mention it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have already contacted them, they said first stop system process then change the permission of file `.htaccess` to read/write/execute and  edit it and I got 33/100 on speed test. It worked for short time, I have tested it with `Google PageSpeed Insights` got the result `Desktop: 71 / 100`(previously it was 33/100). After a few minute the `.htaccess` file revert back to it's initial content. My question is does apache doing this or some background process from  web hosting service ? Do you have any idea?

Comment: It would be helpful to include a screenshot of the pagespeed insight, also make a [phpinfo file](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/12213/20604) without the module in `.htaccess`

Comment: Here the link of my website http://sealindustry.com/ can you please check it directly. and I didn’t get the point `make a phpinfo file without the module in .htaccess`

Comment: Hey Haris, I can do but phpinfo your need to do yourself, since it requires you to upload or create a file on your server. Simply create a file called `whateveryouwant.php` containing just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` then look at the modules. Don't disclose the url path of the php info or delete it once looked.

Comment: By the way the top of your template you have strange characters `�٥` Your need to remove them.

Comment: I can see that GZIP is not enabled and I believe your going to need to contact them again, you shouldn't need to keep resetting processes. Also you have far to many things loading > http://www.webpagetest.org/result/150418_WB_KJ9/1/details/ There's various and questions on Pro Webmasters to help you (You want to combined JS and CSS, then minify them, also get rid of stuff you don't need).

Comment: Also, personally I'd ask them if your on classic hosting, if so they should be able to move you.