# Why is there no apache2handler section?

Tags: php, apache

I try to figure out if the module `mod_expires` is installed. So I created a phpinfo() site and loaded it, but there is no section called **apache2handler** anywhere.

In [this post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/12213/98535) there is apache2handler. I am using PHP Version 5.6.39.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing in the output of `phpinfo()` is the *PHP environment*. Generally, you will only see a list of Apache loaded modules (an apache2handler section) if PHP itself is installed as an Apache module (eg. mod_php). PHP is often installed as CGI/FastCGI, in which case you won't necessarily be able to *detect* (from PHP) whether mod_expires is installed or not.